# TSQL Join and Group Xml Column Values

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, group-by, sqlxml

I have a table like this;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkyB6.png

I want to sum each first 5 columns and string join with comma values in xml column. (It store results like this : `<r><p>example</p><p>example2</p></r>`)

```
select 
    sum(Value1), sum(Value2), sum(Value3), sum(Value4), sum(Value5), 
    (select t.c.value('.', 'varchar(400)') + ',' 
     from Xml.nodes('/r/p') as t(c) 
     for xml path('')), 
    DateTime as DateTime 
from table 
group by DateTime
```

But I'm getting an xml error with group by exception.

> A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

Any help would be awesome for me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do this without subquery:

```
select
    sum(a.Value1),
    sum(a.Value2),
    sum(a.Value3),
    sum(a.Value4),
    sum(a.Value5),
    stuff(
        (
            select ',' + t.c.value('.', 'varchar(400)')
            from table as b
                outer apply b.[Xml].nodes('r/p') as t(c)
            where b.[DateTime] = a.[DateTime]
            for xml path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
    ,1,1,'')
from table as a
group by a.[DateTime]
```

BTW try not to name your columns as types in SQL Server.

**<kbd>[sql fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eef6e/3)</kbd>** with simplified data

Comment: really thanks man! You saved my time :) And yeah i just changed the names for the easiest way thanks again!